# Selenium Firefox Scraping : Takes so much RAM and crash

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Reposted cause by : Not enought desired behavior

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for several days.
I have a python script which scrapes iteratively a dynamic website with selenium using the geckodriver.
During 2 hours it manages to take all of the data that I told to recover and at the end of these 2 hours, it begins to slow down and eventually crash.
The crash is caused by the occupation of firefox in the RAM. In detail, the longer the script scrapes, the more memory Firefox occupies increases.
I scoured the net and found various solutions which did not work.
If you can help me find the solution to be able to scrape for at least 24 hours that would be cool of you.

A bit of code

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/opt/firefox/firefox')

start_time = time.time()
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
        
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)


driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/bin/geckodriver",options=options, firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
        
driver.get("https:********************************")
        
time.sleep(5)
print("WebSite OPENED ready to connect")
        
def auth(t_end) :
print("entering in auth function")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("******************").click()
time.sleep(5)
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("******************")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("*****")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("*****************")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("*****")  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("**************").click()
        
time.sleep(5)
print("Connected ready for Scraping")
    
    def scraping(i, t_end) :

print("entering in scraping function")
os.system("free -h && sysctl vm.drop_caches=3 && free -h")
maps = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("************")

t_end = t_end * 3600
t_end = time.time() + t_end
l_a = []
dit_l_a ={}
time.sleep(5)
while time.time() < t_end :
    dict_tempo = {}
    total_a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("***************").text
    if total_a == '0.00' :
        time.sleep(10.5)
        final_a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("**********").text
        l_a.append(final_a)

        history_a1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('******').text
        scrape = driver.find_element_by_xpath('*******').text
        while scrape == history_a1 : 
            scrape = driver.find_element_by_xpath('****').text
        scrape = scrape.split('\n')
        
        dict_tempo["Final a"] = final_a
        dict_tempo["List Of All a"] = scrape
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        dict_tempo["Date"] = now

        dit_l_a[scrape[0]] = dict_tempo

return dit_l_a
for i in range(168):
    print("Interation : ", i)
    try :
      returned_dict = scraping(i, t_end)
      joblib.dump(returned_dict, './returned_dict_' + str(i))
    except Exception as e :
      print(e)
      pass
return returned_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':

    returned_dict = auth(2)
```

*Environment: VPS 4GB RAM - CentOS 8 - Python 3.8 - Firefox84Beta - GeckDriver 0.28.0 - Headless scraping*

Comment: are you sure its firefox.exe taking memory ? you are appening continously to l_a that wull take up memory #

Comment: It might be an idea to close and reopen the browser occasionally. `driver.close()` closes the tab and `driver.quit()` quits the window.

Comment: @PDHide - i'm 100% that this is firefox taking memory :/

Comment: @WBM - If i `driver.close()` i'll have to realod the page and making auth again. The problem is that i'm scraping a dynamic website and i have to be able to do that action for atleast 24hours...

Comment: What is the actual error condition? A Firefox crash? The script failing?

Comment: @Pixousss Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: your best bet is to use HTMLUnit.  You'll use much less resources.

Comment: Actually it depends on the moment, i had a marionnette error, a scraping error, but all those errors were occured because Firefox crashed

Comment: Keep in mind that if i have to post the stack error now, i'll have to wait 2hours(+ maybe)

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using firefox profile so what you can do is configure your profile to use less memory by following the recommended settings in firefox and then use that

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources

**Additionally**

In script try to add implicit wait of 3 or 4 seconds , this causes all commands to wait for 4 seconds making the scraping process slower if elements are not found or completed.

also add sleep after while and for loop:

```
while time.time() < t_end :
          time.sleep(5)
```

Also

```
for i in range(168):
          time.sleep(5)
```

This results in firefox storing files in harddisk than RAM , If you don't use sleep , the selenium action on the browser will be really fast than firefox could handle. This results in firefox using more RAM to serve the fast demand as read write operation is faster from RAM than harddisk

In addition add driver.close() this wont mostly remove the browser session , if it does try opening url in different tab and closing the previous tab in every 100 iteration or something . This will also free up memory

**You can add sleep before each action using listeners**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time;

from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener


class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Before navigate to %s" % url)

    def find_element_by_id(self, id_, driver):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(5)
            print("helloooo")
        print("After navigate to %s" % url)

    def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(5)
            print("hi")
        print("After navigate to %s" % url)


tempdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = EventFiringWebDriver(tempdriver, MyListener())
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")

driver.find_element_by_id("hi")
```

Read : 7.37. Event Firing WebDriver Support

at : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

THe above example is only for driver, add the same for webelement if you need. But in your case time.sleep() with in loop would be more than enough

Comment: "...add implicit wait of 3 or 4 seconds , this causes all commands to wait for 4 seconds making the scrapping process slower"  That's only true if element is not found.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, let me test it tomorrow and i'll come back and tell u if it change somethings

Comment: Hello there, i didn't had the time today to test it out, i'll try it tomorrow, i'll give you a feedback, thanks one more time for your answer